# Testing Vuex action that calls external api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocha.js, vuex

In my Vue.js project I have the following Vuex action:

```
import { HTTP } from '@/services/http'

export const actions = {
  loginUser ({ commit }, params) {
    HTTP.post(
      'v1/login',
      { email: params.email, password: params.password }
    ).then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.token)
      commit('SET_USER', response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      commit('SET_LOGIN_ERROR', error.response.data.error)
    })
  }
}
```

I'm using Mocha + Karma for unit tests. How can I test that action?

Comment: Before we get into this why even bother to do this at all? If you are reliant on a external API call you could question  how reliable and self contained your tests really are. Wouldn't it be better to mock whatever you need from that call?

Answer (score 1):

It's important that you mock/stub any dependencies. Your first challenge is mocking the `HTTP` service because, as written, your tests won't pass unless you have an Internet connection to the backend server. Look into [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to solve this.

To test actions, I borrowed the idea from [Vuex's suggestion](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/testing.html). Create a stub of the `commit` function that accepts the type and payload of each mutation the action calls and then compare that to what is expected. If the list of expected mutations match the list of mutations the `commit` stub calls when the action is executed, then the action passes the test.

This is a trivial example that I wouldn't use in production, but it helps to illustrate the idea:

```
let count = 0
let errors = []
let mutations = [
  { type: 'SET_USER', payload: 'whatever response.data is expected to be' }
]

function commit(type, payload) {
  const mutation = mutations[count]

  try {
    expect(mutation.type).to.equal(type)
    if (payload) { expect(mutation.payload).to.deep.equal(payload) }
  } catch (error) {
    errors.push(error)
  }

  count++
}

actions.loginUser({ commit }, { email: 'fake@email.com', password: '12345' })
```